# How do I write the following SQL query in Laravel using Eloquent?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I want to write a query in Laravel to retrive all the posts that a particular user has viewed. The `user_id` and the `post_id` is saved in the table named `WatchHistory`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Post
WHERE post_id = (
     SELECT post_id
     FROM WatchHistory
     WHERE user_id = $user_id
);
```

I tried the following :

```
$posts = Post::whereIn('post_id', function($query){
        $query->select('post_id')
            ->from(with(new WatchHistory)->getTable())
            ->where('user_id',$user_id);
        })->get();
```

But it gives me an error that the variable user_id is not defined.

Comment: Does this query correct ? What is for `WHERE user_id = user_id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this :

```
POST::whereIn('post_id', function($query) use($user_id){
            $query->select('post_id')
                ->from(with(new WATHCHISTORY)->getTable())
                ->where('user_id',$user_id);
            })->get();
```

Hope this work for you !!!!

Comment: Actually i tried this first before asking the question. The problem here is that I get an error saying that user_id is not defined, although it was defined within the scope.

Comment: @SaviourTom because you have to use this variable in function like `use ($user_id)` after `function($query)` so it will look like: `function($query) use ($user_id)`.  By the way answer which you've voted as the best answer is by using Query Builder and not the Eloquent.

Comment: I was thinking why it was'nt working. Thanks a lot for the answer. @forexknight

Comment: Oh! thank @forexknight to draw my attention on `use()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

If your user's id is in variable `$user_id`, you can do it like,

```
DB::table('post')->whereIn('post_id',
    DB::table('watchhistory')->where('user_id',$user_id)->pluck('post_id')
)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It works. But i wanted to use eloquent so as to optimize performance.

Comment: I've thought you are not using eloquent so I've added my answer